# OUTPUT clause with UPDATE FROM

Tags: sql-server

In the code below, the `OUTPUT Updated.*` fails when executed as-is, but removing the `FROM` in the `UPDATE` and replacing it with a static value works fine. Is there a different syntax required when using `OUTPUT` with an `UPDATE FROM`?

```
 USE SCRATCH

 CREATE TABLE Tab1(a char(10))
 CREATE TABLE Tab2(a char(10))
 CREATE TABLE Tab3(a char(10))

 INSERT INTO Tab1(a) values ('a')
 INSERT INTO Tab1(a) values ('a')
 INSERT INTO Tab1(a) values ('a')
 INSERT INTO Tab1(a) values ('a')
 INSERT INTO Tab1(a) values ('a')

 INSERT INTO Tab2(a) values ('a')
 INSERT INTO Tab2(a) values ('a')
 INSERT INTO Tab2(a) values ('a')
 INSERT INTO Tab2(a) values ('a')
 INSERT INTO Tab2(a) values ('a')

 UPDATE T1
 SET T1.a = T2.a
 FROM Tab1 T1 JOIN Tab2 T2 ON T1.a = T2.a
 OUTPUT Updated.*
```

The error I get is

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No it's the [same syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

The `output` still goes immediately after the `set`.

There is no `updated` table available though.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.a = T2.a
OUTPUT INSERTED.*,DELETED.*
FROM Tab1 T1 JOIN Tab2 T2 ON T1.a = T2.a
```